# XNA If statement and Random.Next

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna

I created an IF Statement for my XNA game which makes my characters leave their classroom(screen). There are 40 characters, in lines of 10. 'Dest' means destination of the character. This code is in my update method and I have a list of characters in my initialize method:

```
if (activeCharacter.DestX < 680)
{
    activeCharacter.DestX = activeCharacter.DestX + 6;
}
else if (activeCharacter.DestY < 600)                //600
{
    activeCharacter.DestY = activeCharacter.DestY + 6;
}
else if (activeCharacter.DestY == 600)
{
    activeCharacter = classroom[(Random.Next(classroom.Count))];

    Console.WriteLine(activeCharacter.DestY);
```

The aim is to have random characters leave the classroom. When a character from the 1st row leaves, another random character will leave straight after and another depending on if it's from the first row. However if a character from any other row except the 1st leaves, only one character will go.

Can someone please tell me stop this from happening?

Thanks!

Comment: To improve the readability/maintainability of your code, I would like to encourage you to read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad) as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DestY is incremented by 6, until it is bigger then or equal to 600. However the final `else if` only checks for equal to 600.

Changing the final check to:

```
else if (activeCharacter.DestY >= 600)
```

Or simply:

```
else
```

Will most likely solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there a way to also draw one sprite and remove the next sprite when else if (activeCharacter.DestY >= 600) happens?